# What CDN do I use for an Office Add-in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, office-addins, office-ui-fabric

I'm working on Office Add-in projects (O365).   Sample projects from GitHub, and Online documentation from Microsoft show a variety of different CDNs.

I'm not sure which one is for use with React, Fabric-UI.JS, or just simply jQuery.

**To be used with React?**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css">
```

**The Microsoft's Fabric-JS page shows the CDNs below.  However, I see on GitHub that they're on 1.5.0 now.  Is this technology being taken seriously by Microsoft, or have they moved on to other Javascript Library solutions?**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
<script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

**Are these intended for use with React, Fabric-JS, or simply jQuery?**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the CDNs, then yes the [documentation](http://ttps://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/get-started#core) refers it to:

- https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css

Since it is on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-ui-fabric-core)  you could use [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-core@9.6.1/dist/css/) CDNs as well. Such as:

1. https://unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-core@9.6.1/dist/css/fabric.min.css
2. https://unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-core@9.6.1/dist/css/fabric.css

The reason why the documentation website has older version of Fabric is because the Fabric team is working on making it significantly better, here is the preview of the new site https://aka.ms/fabric-preview

If you are building the add-in in React, then you don't need the CDN, you can refer to the styles from the package directly and react-create-app (or custom webpack) will bundle it correctly. If your development environment uses NPM, you can do that too with office-ui-fabric-core as well.

Yes, Microsoft is significantly investing in Fabric! Almost all teams are using it.

Comment: Just so that I am clear.  Are you saying that I can simply use the "9.6.1" CDN regardless of the Javascript Library? (Fabric-UI.js, ReactJs, VueJs, jQuery)

The "appsforoffice.microsoft.com" CDN can be safely ignored?

Comment: Mike from the Fabric team here. To clarify, these URLs are for [Fabric Core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/) which is a CSS library containing basic styles for elements like typography and color. These styles can be used with any framework. [Fabric React](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/) is a separate project that focuses on components (dropdowns, panels, buttons, etc.) that are implemented in React.

Comment: @MikeWheaton
Thank you. When I create an Office Add-in using VS2017 it provides the the "appsforoffice.microsoft.com" CDN.  The Microsoft Getting Started site for Office Fabric recommends the CDN beginning with"static2.sharepointonline.com" .  What is the Microsoft Recommendation, or does it simply not matter?

Comment: Where the same files are on both it shouldn't matter, but I believe the latest releases will only be on sharepointonline.com.

Comment: @MikeWheaton:  Thanks.